# What are the possible tools to convert from pdf to epub?

Tags: pdf, conversion, ocr, epub, calibre

I know similar questions have been asked before, but before marking it as duplicate, let me explain.

I just bought a `.pdf` ebook online and would like to have it as a `.epub` instead. I usually use `calibre` (v1.0.0) to this sort of tasks with great success. This time, a large proportions of lines just seems to get messed up during the conversion.

```
Jérôme disait aimer le rouge. Sa marotte
FRQVLVWDLW VXUWRXW ¡ O#HQOHYHU 'ªJUDIHU OD
dentelle était un geste qu'il effectuait avec la
```

Even if you don't speak french, you'll notice that the middle line is garbage. And it's not only a useless line, it does replace actual content.

The calibre ebook viewer displays the initial `pdf` with the garbage, while it displays just fine with my default pdf viewer. I tried converting to `mobi`, `txt`, `mkd`, to no avail.

I tried `pdftotext`, and the online tool http://www.zamzar.com/ and got the same output.

I then converted the `pdf` to `.pbm` files and tried running `gocr` and `ocrad` on it. The OCR results were quite interesting, but not good enough to be used as-is.

```
Jérôme _sȧit aimer le rouge. Sa marotte
consistait surTout à l'enlever. Dégrafer la
dentelle était un geste qu_l effectuait avec la
```

Would you have any idea of other tools that could help in the process or options to fine-tune calibre or OCR programs ?

Note: I'm running ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Looks like the PDF contains encrypted lines. Probably as anti-copy protection. The PDF also contains a macro which automatically decrypts the lines when viewing, as long as you use  a reader that can handle the embedded macro's. Calibre, zamzar and most other software will use the same method as pdftotext to extract the pure text, without going through the decryption macro. You may have some luck be loading the pdf in Adobe reader (I know, that piece of ***) and exporting it as html. From there you can go to epub. I would try the PDF import from LibreOffice as well.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks for the pointer. I tried LibreOffice, but text is still messed up. I'll try to get my hands on a Windows machine to test the official Adobe reader.

Comment: Something my brother in law suggested: Try ghostscript to convert the PDF from one layout to another (e.g A4 pages to A3 or something like that). The convert might undo the encryption (if you are lucky).

Comment: @Tonny I tried to convert to ghostscript, but it still contains the garbage text in the final output. I'll also try to see if I can a good output from `pdfjs`.